# What datum (reference ellipsoid) does Google Earth use?

Tags: google-earth, datum, geodesy, ellipsoid

**What datum (reference ellipsoid) does Google Earth[1] use?**

I can't seem to find where Google Earth tells explicitly what datum they use. I need some sort of valid link.

[1] The default free version that you download from Google.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Does Google Earth use WGS84 (G1762)?](https://support.google.com/earth/thread/26136033?hl=en):

> Google Earth itself doesnt do any projection or anything, but by
> convention all the data (imagry, KML etc)  'imported' into Google
> Earth uses WGS84.

Comment: Is it important for this question, that the geoid they use is not a perfect WGS84 geoid, but an EGM96 geoid which is a sphere? 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/kml-support-advanced/SL82unzyOfc/yuGWIpHa8rcJ

Comment: Does Google's also use this datum for its [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro0)?

Comment: EPSG 3857, or spherical Mercator, is an interesting one. Since they use a different datum for input and output. https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/the-google-maps-bing-maps-spherical-mercator-projection/

Answer (score 7):

The heights on google earth refer to EGM96 and are, therefore, Geoidal heights. The lat/long are referred to the WGS 84 ellipsoid.

Comment: That is pretty much the same as the SRTM C-Band data available on the net.

Comment: Read http://www.researchgate.net/publication/281194714_Analysis_of_the_accuracy_of_Shuttle_Radar_Topography_Mission_%28SRTM%29_height_models_using_International_Global_Navigation_Satellite_System_Service_%28IGS%29_Network