# How to convert elevation data from Google Elevation API to NAVD 88?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, datum

I want to convert the elevation data obtained from Google elevation API to NAVD 88. I understand that Google uses WGS84 with [EGM96 Geoid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20259/what-datum-reference-ellipsoid-does-google-earth-use).

Do you know what I should do to convert the elevation data? Also, is there any python library that could help me with the conversion?

Comment: EPSG:26915 is a 2D reference system. A conversion from a 3D to a 2D CRS will not transform the elevation values. Do you know to what 3D CRS do you want to transform the elevations?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Thanks a lot for your prompt response. I modified the question. Sorry for my ignorance.